# To reach a file faster, should i search trough all sub folders or just put them together in one folder than do the search?

Tags: filesystems, directory, subdirectory

Lets say i got millions of files seperated into subfolders in a folder and most of them are pictures with ~250kb+..

When i want to reach them it tooks really much time to get that file cause i need to search trough all subfolders.

The folder tree looks like this:

```
      |D
   |B |
   |  |E
 A |
   |  |F
   |C |
      |G
```

Just to make it more understandable lets say

```
A       : is my area. 
B,C     : are my buildings on that area.
D,E,F,G : are my flats of the buildings.
```

and all those flats can change position between buildings and with other flats

```
      |G                |F                |E
   |B |              |B |              |B |
   |  |D             |  |G             |  |F
 A |         OR    A |         OR    A |       
   |  |E             |  |D             |  |G
   |C |              |C |              |C |
      |F                |E                |D
```

so to find out where that flat is i will need to get trough all buildings under that area..

In a position like this. 
If i wait sorting of one folder where all files stands together..
Would it be faster than searching trough many sub folders?

**Edit:** I dont really now much about filesystems but im using win7 and on my disk filesystem shown as NTFS also got a network disk with NTFS filesystem.

Comment: I don't know what kind of buildings you've got there such that flats are able to move between buildings! My flat mostly just stays put... except for that one time when it got depressed and moved to the basement for a couple of months. I talked it into going back to the second floor though. It trusts me. I live inside it after all.

Comment: @Celada lol nice one. I know it looks reall much complicated thats why i tried to explain with buildings and flats. I got folders that moves between other folders as u can see. if we think those folders as items and if you sometimes need to take an item from desk and put on the bed than you wont be able to find that item on ur desk so you start searhing for other locations that it might be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know* the path of the file you want to open, finding it when it is nested in a series of  subdirectories is typically faster than finding a file in one huge directory. Of course it all depends on your filesystem, so it won't hurt to test.

Clarification: If you have to search for the file in *lots* of different places, this could be slower, actually. If you have so many files, the fastest solution would be to make it easier on your filesystem: store the location of each file in a database that maps each (uniquely named) "flat" to its full pathname. This way you can access each file with a single `open` call, and the filesystem will find it very quickly since the intermediate subdirectories are kept small (ish).

Comment: Yea! Thats what i thought either and accepted ur answer cause ur the first guy that answered.

Comment: Thanks. I've added some clarification on further reflection. The biggest speedup will come from using the filesystem less.

Answer (score 1):

Different filesystems perform differently. Which one are you using?

Historically, filesystems had lots of trouble with directories containing lots of files (say, tens of thousands of files or more) because they used **O(n)** algorithms to search within a directory. Most modern filesystems like ext3, ext4, and xfs do not have this problem.

To find out which structure will perform better for you, you either need to benchmark different cases yourself (being sure to pay attention to whether the kernel's directory name lookup cache is hot or cold) or study benchmarks other people have already done on your particular filesystem.